# C : how to create File metadata (header) that include other files details

Tags: c, file-io, header

I have one directory, that contains n number of files, I want to create a blank file with header (metadata) that contains the directory details like Directory name, total number of files, all file names and their file size. I think it is similar to tar header, but i really don't know that how to define/create such kind of header with C program.

I know about header read/write,

```
fwrite(data,sizeof(metadata),1,FILE_POINTER);

fread(data, sizeof(metadata), 1, FILE_POINTER);
```

but before that how can i assign the value dynamically?? how to create header that contains the other directory information?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Can you pls state your original problem statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664536/want-to-create-dynamic-header-for-number-of-files duplicate?

Comment: I want to add several files into one file.