# Want to fill Structure for Metadata

Tags: c, file

Here i have one directory which has number of files.

I want to fill this files all information in one structure.

I have two structures which are following.

```
struct files {

    char *file_name;
    int file_size;
};

typedef struct file_header {

    int file_count;
    struct files file[variable as per number of files];
} metadata;
```

i want to make one header which contains all information regarding these files.

like if i have 3 files than i want to make this structure like this in `file_count = 3` and how can i allocate second variable value?  and want to store file name and file size as per file.

i want file structure like this

```
file_count = 3
file[0].file_name = "a.txt"
file[0].file_size = 1024
file[1].file_name = "b.txt"
file[1].file_size = 818
file[2].file_name = "c.txt"
file[2].file_size = 452
```

I have all logic about file name and file size but how can i fill these things in this structure.?

Code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>



char path[1024] = "/home/test/main/Integration/testing/package_DIR";

//int count = 5;

struct files {

    char *file_name;
    int file_size;
};

typedef struct file_header {

    int file_count;
    struct files file[5];
} metadata;


metadata *create_header();

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/test/main/Integration/testing/file.txt", "w");
    metadata *header;
    header = create_header();
    if(header != NULL)
    {
        printf("size of Header is %d\n",sizeof(metadata));
    }

    if (file != NULL) {

        if (fwrite(&header, sizeof(metadata), 1, file) < 1) {
            puts("short count on fwrite");
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    file = fopen("/home/test/main/Integration/testing/file.txt", "rb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        metadata header = { 0 };
        if (fread(&header, sizeof(header), 1, file) < 1) {
            puts("short count on fread");
        }
        fclose(file);
        printf("File Name = %s\n", header.file[0].file_name);
        printf("File count = %d\n", header.file_count);
        printf("File Size = %d\n", header.file[0].file_size);
    }
    return 0;
}

metadata *create_header()
{
    int file_count = 0;
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * entry;
    dirp = opendir(path);
    metadata *header = (metadata *)malloc(sizeof(metadata));
    while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { /* If the entry is a regular file */

            header->file[file_count].file_name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(entry->d_name));
            strcpy(header->file[file_count].file_name,entry->d_name);
            //Put static but i have logic for this i will apply later.
            header->file[file_count].file_size = 10;
            file_count++;

        }
    }
    header->file_count = file_count;
    closedir(dirp);
    //printf("File Count : %d\n", file_count);
    return header;
}
```

output :

```
size of Header is 88
ile Name = �~8
File count = 29205120
File Size = -586425488
```

Its shows different output. so whats problem here?

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Customize Header(metadata) for files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664536/create-customize-headermetadata-for-files)

Comment: Can i Achieve this thing by linked list?

Comment: @user1089679: Yes, you could use a linked list.  But you really aren't explaining what the problem is.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth problem is nothing but i want to fill values in Structure like this so how can i do this. i want to know about this. in my previous question i put my code but its doesn't given proper values to me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664536/create-customize-headermetadata-for-files

Comment: @user1089679: Please edit your question to show the actual code you are using, and describe what you mean by "doesn't give proper values".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other things, you are using `sizeof` on a pointer variable, but seem to think that gives you the size of the object being pointed to. It doesn't. To do that, use the asterisk operator to make the expression have the type that the pointer points at:

```
printf("size of Header is %d\n", sizeof *metadata);
```

As a side note, notice that `sizeof` is not a function, so you don't need parenthesis. When you do see parenthesis, that's when they're part of the expression (a cast).

Comment: ok thanks for your reply . but i cant able to do code for this so how can achieve this thing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not leaving enough room for the null-terminator:

```
header->file[file_count].file_name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(entry->d_name));
```

Comment: Problem is there i agree but i want to make fill Header like this and want to write in file and read back as well as

Comment: @user1089679: You need to fix all your bugs first.